# foreach() running correct once correctly

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

So I just started learning PDO, and can't figure this one out.

The problem I'm having, is that the loop runs correctly once(it seems atleast) everything gets added to the correct databases, but then it doesn't seem to get the "dkpAmount" from the rest of the array, and doesn't add new dkpAmount to them either.

Please help.

my form looks like this:

```
    <form class="upd-dkp" method="POST" action="inc/update-dkp.inc.php">
    <textarea placeholder="One, Two, Three" id="characters" type="text" class="validate" name="characters"></textarea>
        <input placeholder="10" id="defeated" type="text" class="validate" name="defeated">
        <input placeholder="2" id="wipes" type="text" class="validate" name="wipes">
        <select name="raid">
            <option value="1">Molten Core</option>
            <option value="2">Blackwing Lair</option>
            <option value="3">Ahn'Qiraj</option>
            <option value="4" disabled>Naxxramas</option>
        </select>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

and my update-dkp.inc.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
    
$charname = $newdkp = $dkpAmo = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';
    $raiders = explode(',', trim($_POST['characters']));
    $defeated = $_POST['defeated'];
    $wipes = $_POST['wipes'];

            if($_POST['raid'] == 1) {
                foreach($raiders as $raider) {
                    $newDKP = round((5 * $defeated) - (6 * $wipes));
                    $raid = 'Molten Core';
                 
                    $stmt = $handler->prepare('UPDATE userchars SET dkpAmount = dkpAmount + :newdkp WHERE charName = :charname');
                    $stmt->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':newdkp', $newDKP);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    
                    // adding to history db
                    $dkpAmount = $handler->prepare('SELECT dkpAmount from userchars WHERE charName = :charname');
                    $dkpAmount->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
                    $dkpAmount->execute();
                    $dkpAmount = $dkpAmount->fetchAll();
                    $dkpAmo = $dkpAmount;
        
                    $hist = $handler->prepare('INSERT INTO dkp_history(raidName, dkpInc, dkpAmo, charname, histdate) VALUES(:raid, :dkpInc, :dkpAmo, :charname, :histdate)');
                    
                    $hist->bindValue(':raid', $raid);
                    $hist->bindValue(':dkpInc', $newDKP);
                    $hist->bindValue(':dkpAmo', $dkpAmo);
                    $hist->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
                    $hist->bindValue(':histdate', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                    
                    $hist->execute();
                }
            }
            if($_POST['raid'] == 2) {
                foreach($raiders as $raider) {
                    $newDKP = round((5 * $defeated) - (6 * $wipes) + 35);
                    $raid = 'Blackwing Lair';

                    updateDKP($handler, $raider, $newDKP);

                    getCurrentDKP($handler, $raider);

                    insertHistory($handler, $raid, $newDKP, $dkpAmo, $raider);
                }
            }
            if($_POST['raid'] == 3) {
                foreach($raiders as $raider) {
                    $newDKP = (5 * $defeated) - (6 * $wipes) + 55;
                    $raid = 'Ahn\'Qiraj';
                   
                    $stmt = $handler->prepare('UPDATE userchars SET dkpAmount = dkpAmount + :newdkp WHERE charName = :charname');
                    $stmt->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':newdkp', $newDKP);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    
                    // adding to history db
                    $dkpAmount = $handler->prepare('SELECT dkpAmount from userchars WHERE charName = :name');
                    $dkpAmount->bindValue(':name', $raider);
                    $dkpAmount->execute();
                    $dkpAmount = $dkpAmount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $dkpAmo = $dkpAmount;
        
                    $hist = $handler->prepare('INSERT INTO dkp_history(raidName, dkpInc, dkpAmo, charname, histdate) VALUES(:raid, :dkpInc, :dkpAmo, :charname, :histdate)');
                    
                    $hist->bindValue(':raid', $raid);
                    $hist->bindValue(':dkpInc', $newDKP);
                    $hist->bindValue(':dkpAmo', $dkpAmo);
                    $hist->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
                    $hist->bindValue(':histdate', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                    
                    $hist->execute(); 
                }
            }
            if($_POST['raid'] == 4) {
                foreach($raiders as $raider) {
                    $newDKP = (5 * $defeated) - (6 * $wipes) + 75;
                    $raid = 'Naxxramas';
                   
                    $stmt = $handler->prepare('UPDATE userchars SET dkpAmount = dkpAmount + :newdkp WHERE charName = :charname');
                    $stmt->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':newdkp', $newDKP);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    
                    // adding to history db
                    $dkpAmount = $handler->prepare('SELECT dkpAmount from userchars WHERE charName = :name');
                    $dkpAmount->bindValue(':name', $raider);
                    $dkpAmount->execute();
                    $dkpAmount = $dkpAmount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $dkpAmo = $dkpAmount['dkpAmount'];
        
                    $hist = $handler->prepare('INSERT INTO dkp_history(raidName, dkpInc, dkpAmo, charname, histdate) VALUES(:raid, :dkpInc, :dkpAmo, :charname, :histdate)');
                    
                    $hist->bindValue(':raid', $raid);
                    $hist->bindValue(':dkpInc', $newDKP);
                    $hist->bindValue(':dkpAmo', $dkpAmo);
                    $hist->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
                    $hist->bindValue(':histdate', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                    
                    $hist->execute(); 
            }
        }
        header("Location: ../index.php?dkp=".$newDKP."");
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
?>
```

The code running in my functions, is basically the same as the other 3, but I'll post it anyways:

```
    function updateDKP($handler, $raider, $newDKP) {
    $stmt = $handler->prepare('UPDATE userchars SET dkpAmount = dkpAmount + :newdkp WHERE charName = :charname');
    $stmt->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
    $stmt->bindValue(':newdkp', $newDKP);
    $stmt->execute();
}
function getCurrentDKP($handler, $raider) {
    $dkpAmount;
    $dkpAmo;
    $dkpAmount = $handler->prepare('SELECT dkpAmount FROM userchars WHERE charName = :charname');
    $dkpAmount->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
    $dkpAmount->execute();
    $dkpAmount = $dkpAmount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dkpAmo = $dkpAmount['dkpAmount'];
    return $dkpAmo;
}
function insertHistory($handler, $raid, $newDKP, $dkpAmo, $raider) {
    $hist = $handler->prepare('INSERT INTO dkp_history(raidName, dkpInc, dkpAmo, charname, histdate) VALUES(:raid, :dkpInc, :dkpAmo, :charname, :histdate)');
    
    $hist->bindValue(':raid', $raid);
    $hist->bindValue(':dkpInc', $newDKP);
    $hist->bindValue(':dkpAmo', $dkpAmo);
    $hist->bindValue(':charname', $raider);
    $hist->bindValue(':histdate', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    
    $hist->execute();
}
```

I know this turned into a lot of code on the page. but didn't want there to be anything missing for you to be able to help ^^

*EDIT:
Would also like to mention that it does add to dkp_history with all the correct names, $dkpInc is correct  there aswell - it just doesn't grab $dkpAmount or update $dkpAmount

Solution in comments -> Tried to be descriptive.

Comment: Why do you think this issue is even related to PDO? Did you make sure all values are properly set **before** calling any database interaction?

Comment: Well at least i can spot one issue, $dkpAmount is apparently an array, so it makes no sense to insert int as is. But nevertheless, Stack Overflow is not a "Review my code and make it work" service. You are supposed not only write some wall of code but verify whether it works. Then come up with a concrete question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - You're right, I'm sorry. Just been sitting with this all night, and didn't really know how to ask the question properly.

Comment: You just shouldn't write this amount of code at once. You must write in small parts and obligatory **verify** every part before moving to another. Before every insert query you must inspect every value to be inserted.

Comment: You say the loop runs correctly, but which? you have 4 different loops there, your question is quite too vague and should be more focused, edit the question with the necessary code that is buggy, but before that you should firstly check what your variables contain.

Comment: Whenever you run into a problem like this, break it down into smaller more manageable parts, and try to remove extra noise. For instance, don't worry about `$_POST` and instead bake actual values into the code. So, make a variable called `$raid` and set it to `1`. You can then do `if($raid === 1)` and debug that path completely. Take the other POST values and make them into variables with known and expected values. Once that works, change the variables and continue. Eventually you should be able to set `$raid = $_POST['raid']` and it should just work. But start simple.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

So the solution(s) were easy to implement, but hard to find for me. Was using $_POST['raid'] = 2 - in both my tries.

Solution 1.
The array had spaces in each line EXCEPT the first one, which is why the first foreach() went through without any issues. To fix this I tried a few things, like trim & then explode, but it didn't seem to get rid of the spaces. what I ended up doing:

```
$raiderx = urlencode($_POST['characters']);
$raiders = str_replace("+", "", $raiderx);
$raiders = urldecode($raiders);
$raiders = explode(',', $raiders);
```

urlencode() - turns a space into "+", so it could go into url's without issues, and from there I replaced the + with nothing. Then I used explode() to put it into an array again, and the spaces weren't there anymore.

Solution 2. When running the function:

```
getCurrentDKP($handler, $raider);
```

I had forgotten to make it a variable before. so I did that and it was fixed.

```
$dkpAmo = getCurrentDKP($handler, $raider);
```